# facing problem in designing with flexbox for responsiveness

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I am trying to display two textbox in a row 
I try to make it responsive using flexbox , but I am unable to do that I am putting my code

**.css**

```
.form-container{
   background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px #b7afaf;
    padding: 11px;
    margin: 33px;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: row;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px #b7afaf;
 }


 .flex-container > div {
    margin: 0px 12px;
   font-size: 12px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px #b7afaf;
    padding: 11px;
    margin: 13px;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
[![<form  \[formGroup\]="employeeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)"> 
<div class='form-container'>

    <div class='flex-container'>
        <div><span> First Name </span> 
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <input matInput formControlName='fname'>
           </mat-form-field>  
        </div>
        <div><span> Last Name </span>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <input matInput formControlName='lname' type='text'>
  </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>  

      </div>
      </form>][1]][1]
```

- **I have used Angular material for textbox**
- **It is not responsive and It looks like -->>**

[image: It is not responsive and It looks like]

Comment: can you provide `stackblitz` link of your problem?

Comment: Add media query  for size less than 720:width to css and set display : block in that

Comment: I would add a media query for size less than 720px of width as @GaurangDhorda said, but intead of changing the display, I'd change the flex-direction to `column` instead of `row`.

Comment: It's because of your `input` static `width`.Double check if there is a `width` property on `input`.

Answer (score 0):

an example with your html:

```
 <div class='flex-container'>
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
         <input matInput formControlName='fname'>
     </mat-form-field>  
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input matInput formControlName='lname' type='text'>
      </mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

You should set on mat-form-field a width in % and a min-width:

```
.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap; //if you want it to go to the line if it's too small
}
mat-form-field {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```